# Waiting for a file to be created in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

Is there a built in method for waiting for a file to be created in c#?  How about waiting for a file to be completely written?

I've baked my own by repeatedly attempting File.OpenRead() on a file until it succeeds (and failing on a timeout), but spinning on a file doesn't seem like the right thing to do.  I'm guessing there's a baked-in method in .NET to do this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about using the FileSystemWatcher component ?

This class 'watches' a given directory or file, and can raise events when something (you can define what) has happened.

Comment: Just a caution with FileSystemWatcher - I've found that a FileSystemWatcher can fail when attempting to use it with a drive mounted on the network where the connection is flaky.  Essentially, when the connection was lost and reestablished, the watcher no longer recognized changes. Just my two cents.

Comment: It also doesn't work with Novell Networks at least 1.1 didn't

Answer (score 6):

When creating a file with `File.Create` you can just call the `Close` Function.
Like this:

```
File.Create(savePath).Close();
```

Comment: Even after above code we required to put Delay else it will fail further. So my question is :  why do we put wait if File.Create(filePath) is sync method ?

Answer (score 1):

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) can notify you when a file is created, deleted, updated, attributes changed etc. It will solve your first issue of waitign for it to be created.

As for waiting for it to be written, when a file is created, you can spin off and start tracking it's size and wait for it stop being updated, then add in a settle time period, You can also try and get an exclusive lock but be careful of locking the file if the other process is also trying to lock it...you could cause unexpected thigns to occur.

Answer (score 1):

FileSysWatcher cannot monitor network paths.  In such instances, you manually have to "crawl" the files in a directory -- which can result in the above users error.

Is there an alternative, so that we can be sure we don't open a file before it has been fully written to disk and closed?

Comment: The "dumb but works" method I've used (across network paths) is to put a thread.sleep() in a loop which monitors size.  Check for the file.  If not exists then sleep anyway, if exists then check size and sleep once more.  If next time the size is the same, then quit, if not, sleep again.  I'm looking at 15-20Mb files and sleeping for 5 mins in between...which is overkill but as this is overnight so has no impact.  It's not very clever, but hasn't failed yet.