# Problem with reading text file

Tags: c#, file, timer

I got a problem with reading a text file, it's not the reading it's self that is a problem it is when I should read it.

I got a server program (made by an external company so I got no control over it) where you can put files in. The server see's a new file has arrived reads it and does things with it and then he puts a result back. So I'm waiting for the file to be ready, but I can't read it to early cause I don't know if it exists already. So I'm doing this:

```
while (IsFileLocked(file))
{
    Thread.Sleep(25);
}

private bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
}
```

Now this really helps to check if the file is readable and I never get any IOExceptions anymore when I'm reading. Now I start the reading but sometimes I just read an empty file. And I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be empty. It's not a bug of the server program (I'll explain later).

Here is the code where the problem starts:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = file.OpenText())
{
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
         // here starts the reading
    }
}
```

But when I use this code I don't get the problem:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = file.OpenText())
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
         // here starts the reading
    }
}
```

So my guess is that the file is empty when I can open it but it has no text in it.
I changed the Thread.sleep to 100 miliseconds and then I get the problem again. When I changed it to 500 the problem was solved again.

Now my software needs to run on a lot of different computers so I don't know how fast they are, but I'm afraid if I set the timer to low I might get problems on other computers. But I don't want my users to be waiting for there info to long. 
Is waiting the only option or is there another way?
Will there be a problem on other computers with different hardware configuration?

Edit: I tried FileSystemWatcher, and it is not the solution!

Comment: You could use the FileSystemWatcher to inform you when a file has arrived. That way you know it's there. You will still need to check it's readable as FileSystemWatcher notifies you when the file is created i.e. it could take several seconds to be written to before it's readable. I've implemented a similar solution for processing files that get FTP'd to a directory at various times during the day.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness the file created event is thrown by the watcher when the file is created, but may not yet be readable. When the file is completely written and available it will then throw a 'file changed' event. At that point the file is available.

Comment: Adding a FileSystemWatcher did not solve my problem I just got the same problem again. Even with the watcherchangetypes I keep reading an empty file. And when I use a Thread.sleep() it works perfect again. So it looks like filesystemwatcher is nothing more then a .net implementation of my code.

Answer (score 0):

[Waiting for a file to be created in C# - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508534/waiting-for-a-file-to-be-created-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The tool you need to add is a FileWatcher (see [MSDN System.IO.FileWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)). This will allow you to monitor activity and add event handlers to response to file events. You can respond to file created by adding a handler for file changed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do like this:

http://olioul.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/4-text-readwrite-in-text-document/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.